# Don't know which file I'm downloading

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to download a file, from a link that looks like:
www.sample.com/download.php?id=1234231

I don't know which file I'll get from this link.
First I tried `webclient.downloadfile(link,path)` - but the path I gave as the folder that the file should be in gave me an access denied error.
My problem is that I can't determine the file I'll get.

I've tried something like:

```
var wreq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
using (var res = (HttpWebResponse) wreq.GetResponse())
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        //get filename Header
        var filenameHeader =
            res.GetResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")
               .Split(';')
               .Where(s => s.Contains("filename"))
               .ToList()[
                   0];
        var fileName = filenameHeader.Replace(" ", "").Split('=')[1];
        //clear fileName
        fileName = fileName.Replace(":", "");
        using (var writer = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(folderToSave , fileName),FileMode.Create))
        {
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't there something simpler than that?
Is is there any chance that I will download a file and not get a "Content-Disposition" header?

Last thing, at the moment I'm trying to write the file using a `StreamWriter` but the resulting file is corrupted. I assume that this is something related to not writing in binary format, but I'm not sure.

I've also checked the "Content-Length" header and it was a different value than the `response.GetResponse().ToString().Length`, maybe the header is counted it the length as well?

Comment: folderToSave... what is that value.. fileName what is that value.. have  you Debugged this code...?

Comment: No, you’re not guaranteed to get a `Content-Disposition` header, but this is more or less how browsers do it, too. If there is no `Content-Disposition` header with a filename, the last portion of the URL is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend WebClient class for this

```
  class MyWebClient : WebClient
  {
     public string FileName { get; private set; }

     protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
     {
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);

        FileName = Regex.Match(((HttpWebResponse)response).Headers["Content-Disposition"], "filename=(.+?)$").Result("$1");
        string regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
        Regex r = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(regexSearch)));
        FileName = r.Replace(FileName, "-");
        return response;
     }
  }
```

Usage:

```
     MyWebClient mwc = new MyWebClient();
     byte[] bytes = mwc.DownloadData("http://subtitle.co.il//downloadsubtitle.php?id=202500");
     File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(folderToSave, mwc.FileName), bytes);
```

Comment: i dont fully understand how to use this derived class :S
getResponse uses GetWebReponse? , 
and i try to debug it and see what ReponseUri contains and i dont see how i can get out the fileName from there:S

Comment: reponseURI represent the path that show in the url address ,
lets asy my site is:
www.example.com/download.php?id=5
so the absolutePath will be download.php which is incorrent because its t he page name and not the file name which im looking for:S

Comment: tyvm:) but ill return to my original question , there is any chance that the header "Content-Disposition" wont be sent from the server ?

Comment: @roee when it's about downloading file it should exist, but I still would check it and try to handle "Location" header, one of them must exist.